# Color table in html when the value is greater than 1

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this table in my html and it automatically updates when the spreadsheet is updated.

Want I want is when the td value is greater than 1 it will change it's background to "red".

Is that possible?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can you provide your current script? And can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75529145/change-table-tr-color-if-value-is-greater-than-0 kindly visit this link. I have the code pasted there. Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about something like data validation in Google Sheets.  You have an html table.  If the numeric value in a cell is greater then 1 then the background is red?  Does the validation only occur when the table is created?  Or if the user enters a value in the cell the data validation is checked?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of using HTML Template to load a Google Sheet table into an HTML page and do data validation of the values.

Code.gs

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Test");
  menu.addItem("Show Test","showTest");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function showTest() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Test");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(),"Test");
}

function getData() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    return values;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

HTML_Test

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include("CSS_Test"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <? var data = getData(); ?>
    <table id="myTable">
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
    <?!= include("JS_Test"); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS_Test

```
<style>
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
  } 
  td {
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
```

JS_Test

```
<script>
  function validateTable() {
    try {
      let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      for( let i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++ ) {
        let row = table.rows[i];
        let cells = row.cells;
        for( let j=0; j<cells.length; j++ ) {
          let value = cells[j].innerHTML;
          if( parseInt(value) === 1 ) {
            cells[j].style.background = "red";
            cells[j].style.color = "white";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }

  (function () {
    try {
      validateTable();
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }
  )();
</script>
```

Results

[image]

Comment: Will the data update realtime when there is a sudden changes on the google sheet without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: I leave that up to you.  I don’t know how you update the table.

Comment: I'm having error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') (line 9)"

Comment: Line 9 of what?  Post your code so we can see where the error is occuring.