# Change table "TR" color if value is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML made from app-script. In my website, I  have a table where the data's in it is coming from the spreadsheet. If I update the spreadsheet it will automatically update the data in the HTML table without refreshing the page.

What I want is when the value on "TR" is greater than 0 it will change it font color to red without refreshing the whole page. In my code "setInterval" I have a refresh time of 2 seconds. I also want to have this function for the changing of font color on the table.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  setInterval(function() {
    let data1 = document.getElementById('data1');
    let data2 = document.getElementById('data2');
    let data3 = document.getElementById('data3');
    let data4 = document.getElementById('data4');
    let data5 = document.getElementById('data5');
    let data6 = document.getElementById('data6');
    let data7 = document.getElementById('data7');
    let data8 = document.getElementById('data8');
    let data9 = document.getElementById('data9');
    let data10 = document.getElementById('data10');

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(data => {
        data1.innerHTML = data[0];
        data2.innerHTML = data[1];
        data3.innerHTML = data[2];
        data4.innerHTML = data[3];
        data5.innerHTML = data[4];
        data6.innerHTML = data[5];
        data7.innerHTML = data[6];
        data8.innerHTML = data[7];
        data9.innerHTML = data[8];
        data10.innerHTML = data[9];
      })
      .setAutomatically();
  }, 1000)

})

window.onload = function() { // After all the contents has loaded
  var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("number"); //select all the table cell tags
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { //iterate through each of them
    //check if content is more than 0
    if (parseFloat(cells[i].textContent || cells[i].innerText) > 0) {
      cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"; //change background to red
    }
  }
};
```

```css
#datatable {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

#datatable td,
#data-table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#datatable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#datatable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#datatable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Commercial Tasks</th>
    <th># of Pending Tasks</th>
    <th># Completed Tasks</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold" width="250">Credit Bag</td>
    <td id="data1" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>
    <td id="data6" style="text-align:center"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">Exclusivity</td>
    <td id="data2" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>
    <td id="data7" style="text-align:center"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">CBD Removal</td>
    <td id="data3" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>
    <td id="data8" style="text-align:center"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">Churn Single Site</td>
    <td id="data4" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>
    <td id="data9" style="text-align:center"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">Churn Non Single Site</td>
    <td id="data5" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>
    <td id="data10" style="text-align:center"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What I mean is value on td with the class="number" to change it's font color when the value is greater than 0 and when the value drop to 0 again the font will go back to black.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this

Note the cells are read at load time. I think you have paging, if so the code will need amending

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("number"); //select all the table cell tags
   const checkNum = () => {
     google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(data => {
         data.forEach((num, i) => {
           if (i >= cells.length) return; // please note we may have to handle paging here
           cells[i].textContent = +num;
           cells[i].closest("tr").toggleClass("zero", +num === 0); // setting the parent row to red if that ONE cell is 0. If more than one cell per row, we need a total
         })
       })
       .setAutomatically();
   };
   /* -------------------- */
   checkNum(); // run - 
   setInterval(checkNum, 1000);
 })

/* REMEMEBER TO ADD THIS TO THE STYLE CSS 

#datatable tr.zero {
  background-color: red;
}

*/
```

Example with test data

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("number"); //select all the table cell tags
  const data = [1,0,2,0,2,5]; // test
  const checkNum = () => { // remove and rename checkNumGoogle to checkNum when happy
    const total = 0;
    data.forEach((num, i) => { 
      if (i >= cells.length) return; // please note we may have to handle paging here
      cells[i].textContent = +num;
      cells[i].closest("tr").classList.toggle("zero", +num === 0)
    })
  };
  /* -------------------- */
  checkNum(); // run - 
  setInterval(checkNum, 1000);
})
```

```css
#datatable {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

#datatable td,
#data-table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#datatable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#datatable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#datatable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}

#datatable tr.zero { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Commercial Tasks</th>
    <th># of Pending Tasks</th>
    <th># Completed Tasks</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold" width="250">Credit Bag</td>
    <td id="data1" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>
    <td id="data6" style="text-align:center"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">Exclusivity</td>
    <td id="data2" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>
    <td id="data7" style="text-align:center"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">CBD Removal</td>
    <td id="data3" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>
    <td id="data8" style="text-align:center"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">Churn Single Site</td>
    <td id="data4" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>
    <td id="data9" style="text-align:center"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">Churn Non Single Site</td>
    <td id="data5" style="text-align:center" class="number"></td>
    <td id="data10" style="text-align:center"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nothing happens :<

Comment: You need to add a class, and do stuff yourself. Also look in the console, I might have errors. I cannot test on the snippet I made you since it does not have data

Comment: I had a typo (toggleClass instead of classList.toggle. I made you a running example

Comment: The data from "# pending task" and "# completed task" came from google spreadsheet. If sheet is updated, the value from the HTML table will also change real time. Your code is awesome! However, I'm unable to use it as I'm not that good at coding, this is my 2nd time making a website from google spreadsheet using app script. On the "# pending task" column, if the value is greater than 0 it'll change it background color to red, if the value is 0 again, it'll change to it's default color without refreshing the page. Is that possible?

Comment: window.onload = function() { // After all the contents has loaded
  var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("number"); //select all the table cell tags
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { //iterate through each of them
    //check if content is more than 0
    if (parseFloat(cells[i].textContent || cells[i].innerText) > 0) {
      cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"; //change background to red
    }
  }
}; this is the only part of the coded I needed to change :< as it's not working the way I wanted it to be. The rest of the code is good.

Comment: My code does what you want. You just have to add the CSS `#datatable tr.zero { background-color: red; }` to you css and change your script to what I wrote. You can remove the other code. Then remove `/* --- remove when happy */ test code /*----------- */` and rename checkNumGoogle to checkNum

Comment: this my sample spreasheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ICb4tpNaAqJ7_dqf0PBK7vJb5CYCAx0lOfoPsms9VkI/edit?usp=sharing. and this is the sample website. Can you check it?thank you so much! https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzKhIuOFI7gJqBq7e8I3PrLkPeQDToSNYEgHXJzdISf8nDIeqxAUBuO6_qAgod89qiE/exec

Comment: I updated my answer to show just the code you need. No need for your window.onload

Comment: It's somehow working, but it can only display for the "Credit Bag" and the rest of the TR is blank. Also, when the value is greater than 0 it doesn't change the background color :<

Comment: I can only test with the HTML you provide. Look at the example. If the test data looks like what you get back from google, then my code works. If not then I need an example

Comment: Here's the app script website: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzKhIuOFI7gJqBq7e8I3PrLkPeQDToSNYEgHXJzdISf8nDIeqxAUBuO6_qAgod89qiE/exec and here's the google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ICb4tpNaAqJ7_dqf0PBK7vJb5CYCAx0lOfoPsms9VkI/edit?usp=sharing. you can try coding here :<

Comment: I am on vacation without access to a computer. Sorry